# How to execute action only once in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have been using this script to show modal popup window on my site with some QR code inside and it works on single pages but on category pages its called multiple times and because of that it shows 10 times the same window. How can I limit this to be showed only once on the nearest ancor position?

Code:

```
    <li class="qrcode">
    <a  class="popup-trigger"></a>

  </li> 
</ul>
<div class="contain-popup">

<div class="popup">
my qr code
  <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
// Popup Window
var scrollTop = '10';
var newHeight = '100';

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  scrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
  newHeight = scrollTop + 100;
});

$('.popup-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if(jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    $(this).after( $( ".popup" ) );
    $('.popup').show().addClass('popup-mobile').css('top', 0);

  } else {
    $('.popup').removeClass('popup-mobile').css('top', newHeight).toggle();
  };
});

$('html').click(function() {
  $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e){
  $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popup').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: fixed with css, by asigning position:fixed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was quite simple, I don't know how I missed it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.popup-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.caption').find('.popup');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve it is to [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it's html with hiding it at the same time:

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.popup').hide();
  $('.popup').remove();
});
```

Comment: It seems not to be working, can you please write the whole code, maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hide(), remove the class assign to it.
 $('.popup').remove();

Comment: It seems not to be working, can you please write the whole code, maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Popup Window
var scrollTop = '10';
var newHeight = '100';

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  scrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
  newHeight = scrollTop + 100;
});

$('.popup-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if(jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    $(this).after( $( ".popup" ) );
    $('.popup').show().addClass('popup-mobile').css('top', 0);

  } else {
    $('.popup').removeClass('popup-mobile').css('top', newHeight).toggle();
  };
});

$('html').click(function() {
  $('.popup').hide();
  $('.popup').remove();
});

$('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e){
  $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popup').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="qrcode">
    <a  class="popup-trigger"></a>

  </li> 
</ul>
<div class="contain-popup">

<div class="popup">
my qr code
  <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried like this but it does not work. This seems the problematic part $('.popup').remove(); Sublime shows this as invalid.